# Detect Download Managers Requests in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, download, download-manager

i have a ASP.NET MVC application which has an action method with resume support for download pdf files.
When i get download link in browser, action method Only run `Once` BUT when i get download link from a download manager(i.e internet download manager) this action method run `Several` time.

What is problem?

**How i can detect request come from download managers?**

Answer (score 0):

Download manager is an Application & its making *http* request to download file, its not possible to check whether request is coming from specific application.

Alternatively, you can check such scenario in ***Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute*** event in your Global.asax.cs.